# Cross-site publishing of pages library

Tags: 2013, publishing-page, cross-site-publishing

In the past we have set up cross-site publishing using lists and libraries as described in tutorials [like this](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2012/09/sharepoint-cross-site-publishing-step-by-step/) and [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/02/18/an-introduction-to-cross-site-publishing/). We have configured search, CSWP, used facets, created managed navigation, and friendly URL remapping. Everything works.

I am now trying to setup cross-site publishing using a Pages library. In [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635877.aspx#BKMK_SiteStructure) it talks about using a Pages library and seems to suggest this is a great way to use the features of cross-site publishing.

In the two years I have been working with SharePoint and cross-site publishing I have never actually seen a tutorial or documentation on how to actually do this. Every tutorial I've found uses the built-in products list or just a regular list.

And I've had a hard time searching because the words "pages" and "publishing" and "page layout" are part of every discussion regarding cross-site publishing.

**First question** Does anybody know of a good tutorial showing how to uses a Pages library in a cross-site situation?

**My current challenge**

I've set up a **pages library** for sharing and connected it to my remote site. The information is coming across and I've got the category pages working. But when we get down to the item page through navigation, I'm not getting the content. Or if I search on a known word that is only in the page content the search shows me the correct result, but when I click the result it takes me to the category item page. The category item generated when I connect the catalog includes these pieces of managed metadata:

- Created by
- Created
- The term I chose for categorizing the catalog
- ListItemID
- Edited
- Hide physical URLs from search
- **DocId URL** (We have it the unique doc id feature enabled)
- A comments/description column we added
- The publishing contact owner
- **Publishing Page Layout URL**

The Page Content of the publishing page isn't there, nor some of the other stuff like the Page Image.

**Second question** How do I reassemble the Publishing Page on my user site? How do I combine PublishingPageLayoutOWSURLH with all the metadata that is described for that page layout? Especially since the users don't have access to my catalog site.

Comment: Stumbled across this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn144674.aspx. It says that PublishingPageContentOWSHTML is supposed to be on the item page by default, but it wasn't. I've added it and yes I do get that now, but how do I incorporate the page layout?

Comment: did you get anywhere with this? Thanks

Comment: Not really. For whatever reason this whole part of cross-site publishing seems to be a black hole.

Comment: I managed to get something working, just a POC . I came away from my POC thinking that you cannot just use XSP to create a COPY of a site. The site has to be designed with XSP right at the start.

Comment: Dear Rothrock, have you got this working anyhow , I'm with same requirement and struugling with this , any kind of help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Esaki - We've used cross-site publishing for years and everything about it has been a mess. I would recommend not using it if you can find some other way.